# drupal_mail() returns true but unable to send mail

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-hooks

I have written a drupal module with custom form api which will send email to my inbox on each submit. I have written a condition under drupal_mail which returns true but shows an error message "Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists."

Below my code:

```
function my_module_name_mail($key, &$message, $params)
{
    $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal'
);

    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
    }

    $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
    $message['body'] = $params['body']; 
}

function my_module_name_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    $from = $form_state['values']['email'];
    $body= 'Name: '.$name.'<br />Email: '.$email;
    $to = "my_mail_id@example.com";

    $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'Website Information Request',
);

drupal_mail('my_module_name', 'some_mail_key', $to, language_default(), $params, $from, TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Drupal logs for more clues. Enable `devel` / `devel-admin` modules. Once you do, drupal_mail will pipe emails to your temp directory, which will help you narrow down if the problem is with your email server or the config.